# Why isn't there `\textsf` commands, and what should we do about it?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax, font

Currently MathJax supports several fonts for text in mathematics:

$$normal,\mathbf{mathbf},\mathsf{mathsf},\mathrm{mathrm},\mathtt{mathtt}.$$
(And I intentionally omitted all the `\mathbb`,`\mathscr`,`\mathfrak` and `\mathcal` which are really not used for text usually.)

In addition, MathJax also supports the `\text` command which allows one to insert text mid-math mode (and thus retain some basic spacing between words and letters which are otherwise ignored). It also supports $\textbf{textbf}$ and $\textrm{textrm}$ and $\textit{textit}$ explicitly. However $\textsf{textsf}\ $ and $\texttt{texttt}$ -- are unsupported.

Still, not all is lost. We can use a small hack and do the following: `\mathsf{\text{...}}` to get the same functionality as `\textsf{...}` would have given us: $$\mathsf{\text{This is a short sentence in mathmode using a \textsf{} hack}.}$$

---

Since this functionality "almost" exists in MathJax, two questions are needed to be asked:

1. Why isn't `\textsf` and `\texttt` are part of MathJax, like their boldface/italics/serif counterparts?
2. If there is no plan to incorporate these fonts into MathJax, should we request the StackOverlords to include these two definitions for them: `\newcommand{\textsf}[1]{\mathsf{\text{#1}}}` and `\newcommand{\texttt}[1]{\mathtt{\text{#1}}}` for us?

Comment: +1, thanks for bringing this up; it's bugged me too. While we're requesting fonts: I would really like support for the Euler calligraphic font (from the `eucal` package). If I were king of MathJax, I would keep the command `\mathcal` as is, and use `\eucal` for the Euler calligraphic font.

Comment: Zev, I *know* that this bugged you. ;-) But it also bugged me for quite a long time now...

Comment: I have opened a feature request for this on the MathJax issue tracker:  https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/477

Comment: @Davide: Thanks. I was hoping you'll see this and reply (Peter didn't know to tell me why these commands are not implemented, and suggested I post on the github tracker, or here for a custom macro until such feature is inserted. I chose the latter so that you might come and shed some light, but opening this request seems like there's no actual reason...)

Comment: There is no reason not to have `\textsf` and `\texttt` (other than my ignorance of all the LaTeX macros out there that people use).  They weren't in the list I was working from.  As for `\eucal`, that is another story, for two reasons:  1) it would require additional web fonts, and 2) since MathJax maps everything to MathML, there would need to be a way to notate it.  There is no `mathvariant` that could be used for that, so MathJax would need to use something non-standard to do that.  It is possible, but a bit awkward.

Comment: @Zev: Ping.${}{}$

Comment: @Davide: Thank you for that last comment.

Comment: @Zev But we already have `\mathscr` and `\mathcal` (which are distinct)! Yet another calligraphic font seems excessive...

Comment: @Zev: Happy day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has been resolved in MathJax 2.4 (which has deployed in beta).

$$\Large\textsf{This is}\ldots\texttt{awesome.}$$

Comment: For other people as lazy as me: The source for the above is `$$\Large\textsf{This is}\ldots\texttt{awesome.}$$`